# Devise 2.1 are salts off by default?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, mongoid

devised moved the [encryptable module to a different gem](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise-encryptable). However, they state that Bcrypt already uses a salt by default. I'm a bit confused. Without adding `:encryptable` to my models, are they salted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

:encryptable is used for encryption methods other than the default. The default encryption method bcrypt is salted. It is an interface which Devise can use so that you can also define other encryption methods.

See [How can bcrypt have built-in salts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6832445/how-can-bcrypt-have-built-in-salts) for details of the salt and how it is stored.