# Password_hash and default salt is it enough?

Tags: php, bcrypt, password-hash

I was wondering if

`password_hash("custompassgoeshere", PASSWORD_BCRYPT)`

Is secure enough in order to store passwords to the DB or if I should add some more SALT in it (I was thinking something like user's username/email/date of birth/etc).

Thanks!

Comment: Unique salts for each user is recommended. You can just generate a unique salt for each user and store it in the database.

Comment: Perhaps increasing the cost, but using the default salt generation of password_hash() is the recommended option rather than creating your own salt

Comment: Salting an already salted hash is pointless. Bcrypt salts automatically.

Comment: @DamienBlack - This is what `password_hash()` already does, it generates a safe salt from the random source of the operating system, and adds it to resulting hash string. You cannot generate a better salt on your own, so you should not pass one to the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bcrypt would be secure enough on its own., ensure that you increase the iterations/cost to something high enough (but not too slow for your server). You may need to test a few values to test for acceptable hashing times.

You do **not** need to salt your passwords, Bcrypt generates unique salts for each hash automatically and stores it with the hash.

See: [How can bcrypt have built-in salts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6832445/how-can-bcrypt-have-built-in-salts)

Comment: Thank you for the reply and link mate. Any idea how I can check out which would be the best cost value for my server?

Comment: Sure, just create a simple page and hash a string, see how long it takes. You can do this manually. You could also use `microtime` to save the start time before you hash and `microtime` again after the hash to see how long it takes. PHP also has a good example of how to calculate a cost on their documentation page: http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php See example #4

Comment: To the downvoter, care to add a comment as to why this is not a useful answer?