# What is the warden data in a Rails/Devise session composed of?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, warden

The "data" in a Rails session looks like this:

```
{"warden.user.user.key" => [[1], "long-random-string"]}
```

1 is the user id. What is the long random string?

Is this something handled/used by Rails, or Devise?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

When you login a `user`(Devise model name `User`),  a key `"warden.user.model_name.key"` is created which in your case is `"warden.user.user.key"`.

For example:

```
{ warden.user.user.key => [[1], "$2a$10$KItas1NKsvunK0O5w9ioWu"] }
```

where

`1` is the `id` of the logged in user.

`$2a$10$KItas1NKsvunK0O5w9ioWu` aka `long-random-string` is the **partial encrypted password** of user with id `1`.

You can verify this by going on `rails console` and executing

```
User.find(1).encrypted_password  
## => "$2a$10$KItas1NKsvunK0O5w9ioWuWp4wbZ4iympYMqVCRmmvTGapktKqdMe"
```

**UPDATE**

> *could you tell me a bit more about this partial encrypted password? why is it partial and not full?*

To answer your above question in the comment, `Devise` stores the partial `encrypted_password` in the session by invoking `authenticatable_salt` method. `Devise` stores the partial `encrypted_password` as it is more reliable rather than exposing the full encrypted_password in the session(even though its encrypted). That's why the first 30 characters`[0,29]` of the `encrypted_password` are extracted and stored in the session.

```
  # A reliable way to expose the salt regardless of the implementation.
  def authenticatable_salt
    encrypted_password[0,29] if encrypted_password
  end
```

You can see the code for **[authenticatable_salt](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/5b49bd3450b208f627fa9052f376c520d523a5ae/lib/devise/models/database_authenticatable.rb#L136-L138)** here.

> *where/when is it used? is it used by Devise, or by Rails, or both?*

It is used by `Devise` for authentication purpose to verify whether or not a particular user is logged in. Ideal use-case would be, how a particular Rails application keeps track of how a user is logged in when a new page is requested. As HTTP requests are stateless, it would be impossible to tell that a given request actually came from that particular user who is logged in? This is why sessions are important as they would allow the application to keep a track of the logged in user from one request to another until the session expires.

Comment: thank you! could you tell me a bit more about this partial encrypted password? why is it partial and not full? where/when is it used? is it used by Devise, or by Rails, or both?

Comment: (or feel free to direct me to somewhere to read about this -- but i couldn't find a good explainer anywhere)

Comment: @JohnBachir Please read my updated answer. Hope it helps you to understand.

Comment: epic answer-- thanks! points! i'm still a little unclear what the purpose is, but now it's easy for me to explore it myself. (i don't understand how this is related to a salt. salts are typically and strings stored with a user used to perform a 1-way hash and to make a stolen hash useless for guessing the plaintext pw).

Comment: there's some extra insight at http://www.jonathanleighton.com/articles/2013/revocable-sessions-with-devise/ about the salt being used to invalidate existing sessions when the password is changed: the new password's salt will be different to the one stored in the session, so the session is rejected. More about the string's content at http://stackoverflow.com/a/6833165/395180