# spring boot using BcryptPasswordEncoder , the passwords are not matching

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf, bcrypt

Spring boot application, user want to change the password after login but i the function is not changing the password.

```
    @PostMapping("/settings/passwordupdate")
    public String PasswordUpdate(@RequestParam("oldPassword") String oldPassword,
            @RequestParam("newPassword") String newPassword, Principal principal) {

         
        String userName = principal.getName();
        User currentUser = serviceUserDetail.findByUserName(userName);
        final BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        System.out.println(newPassword + " ||||  " + passwordEncoder.encode(currentUser.getPassword()));    
        if (passwordEncoder.matches(oldPassword, passwordEncoder.encode(currentUser.getPassword()))) {
             
            System.out.print("match");
            
        } else {
            System.out.print("not match");
        }
        return "redirect:/";
    }
```

the result is

```
pass ||||  $2a$10$Y3JMpBg/3l4SHJY/X8XRS.O3vLxr64iLLoLY3r933irwsnrvCIr2q
not match---------------
```

while i can login via the password "pass" which means the password is okey

Comment: Might be that one of them are too salty:P https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25844419/why-bcryptpasswordencoder-from-spring-generate-different-outputs-for-same-input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot match the new password with the old password encoded again. **You can match the old password in the parameter with the current password.**

You can try it like this:

```java
if (passwordEncoder.matches(oldPassword, currentUser.getPassword())) {
    String encodedNewPassword = passwordEncoder.encode(newPassword);
    // Store encoded new password..
}
```

See also **[`BCryptPasswordEncoder.matches(java.lang.CharSequence rawPassword, java.lang.String encodedPassword)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/crypto/bcrypt/BCryptPasswordEncoder.html#matches-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.String-)**

Comment: so how i can check if the password provide is same as old password in the database

Comment: Send user's current password to **matches** method after `oldPassword`. Example: `passwordEncoder.matches(oldPassword, currentUser.getPassword())`