# Upgrading Spring Security PasswordEncoder

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Upgrading from:

```
import org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.PasswordEncoder;

    @Override
    public String encodePassword(String plainPassword, Object salt) {
        final String finalSalt = salt != null ? salt.toString() : "";
        return DigestUtils.md5Hex(finalSalt + plainPassword);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isPasswordValid(String encodedPassword, String plainPassword, Object salt) {
        final String enteredPassword = encodePassword(plainPassword, salt);
        return encodedPassword.equals(enteredPassword);
    }
```

To:

```
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;

    @Override
    public String encode(CharSequence rawPassword) {
      final String finalSalt = salt != null ? salt.toString() : "";
      return DigestUtils.md5Hex(finalSalt + plainPassword);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean matches(CharSequence rawPassword, String encodedPassword) {
       final String enteredPassword = encodePassword(plainPassword, salt);
       return encodedPassword.equals(enteredPassword);
    }
```

1. Not sure what to do about `salt`?
2. Not sure if I can just convert `rawPassword` to `String` to replace `plainPassword`?

Comment: Please don't use MD5 for password hashing, it's not considered safe for a long time.

Answer (score 1):

The new methods expect that salt is part of the encoded password.  As per [`PasswordEncoder.encoder()` javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.5.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/crypto/password/PasswordEncoder.html#encode(java.lang.CharSequence)):

> Encode the raw password. Generally, a good encoding algorithm applies a SHA-1 or greater hash combined with an 8-byte or greater randomly generated salt.

If you look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34210582/1602555) it shows how `BCryptPasswordEncoder` encodes salt in the encoded password. The actual BCrypt encoded password format is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6833165/1602555).

Comment: So the new `encode` method should basically just do this? `return new org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder().encode(rawPassword);` and what about the new `matches` method? `return encodedPassword.equals(enteredPassword);`?

Comment: Also, do you know if `SystemWideSaltSource` should be deleted now? Mine was set to `super.setSystemWideSalt("pc567");` and I suspect that changing this may cause some issues