# Guessing the salt of a known password in Meteor

Tags: meteor, bcrypt

My goal is to store the hash and salt of meteor password on another database. So far I've managed to know the hash but not the salt....

Is there a way to deduce the salt used by bcrypt ?

Or is there a way to know the salt used ?

And does Meteor create a new salt each time a password is hashed ?

A "solution" could be the creation of one well known password and deduce the salt out of it if Meteor doesn't change the salt each time.

Any ideas ?

Comment: the following questions answered pretty well : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6832445/how-can-bcrypt-have-built-in-salts