# Retrieving password salt with BCryptPasswordEncoder in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, password-encryption

It appears that `org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder` doesn't return the generated **password salt**:

```
public String encode(CharSequence rawPassword) {
    String salt;
    if(this.strength > 0) {
        if(this.random != null) {
            salt = BCrypt.gensalt(this.strength, this.random);
        } else {
            salt = BCrypt.gensalt(this.strength);
        }
    } else {
        salt = BCrypt.gensalt();
    }

    return BCrypt.hashpw(rawPassword.toString(), salt);
}
```

**Question** : what purpose is that designed for? How can this be used, since it doesn't return a **salt**, which should be stored for the password checking?

Comment: Please Refer answer of this You will get your Answer Possibly  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6832445/how-can-bcrypt-have-built-in-salts

Comment: Are you sure that the information returned from `hashpw` does not include the salt itself?

Comment: @khelwood I'm not sure, so this could be the answer. But `spring-security` failed to check password in login process without giving him actual salt

Comment: Which basically points to an issue with the setup of login configuration / authentication provider. Post the configuration.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apparently, the salt is part of the encrypted String, which is separated by $.

More information can be found here: [How can bcrypt have built-in salts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6832445/how-can-bcrypt-have-built-in-salts)

Comment: Yes, it is. But `DaoAuthenticationProvider` failed to extract it because its `SaltSource` is null. It would be brilliant if you expand your answer and provide additional info how to configure it to automatically extract this `$` separated salt.

Comment: You don't need to extract the salt you need to make sure that the `BCryptPasswordEncoder` is setup for validation. You don't nor should use the `SaltSource`.

Comment: @M.Deinum could you please clarify this point, because this one `auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder())` doesn't work

Comment: Then I doubt that that is the one that is actually being used and/or that you aren't returning the correct password in your custom `UserDetailsService`. You have to make sure that the returned user contains the password from the database.

Comment: I found the mistake in my code. Many sorry about it and thank you;.