# Column 'salt' cannot be null at FOS user create

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony, fosuserbundle

It worked some time ago but now for some reason it produces exception. I have custom User entity and it extends FOS user:

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\UserRepository")
* @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
*/
class User extends BaseUser
{
...
}
```

There is no setSalt() in my custom class. And as I can see in dumped SQL query other not custom fields (email_canonical, enabled, password, ...) are set properly. What else could I check?

**UPDATE**

I did composer update. Here is my composer.json

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "symfony/symfony": "3.2.*",
    "doctrine/orm": "^2.5",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^1.6",
    "doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle": "^1.2",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^2.3",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^2.8",
    "symfony/polyfill-apcu": "^1.0",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "^5.0",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "^2.0",
    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~2.0@dev",
    "hwi/oauth-bundle": "^0.5.1",
    "twig/extensions": "^1.4"
},
```

Comment: Did you updated FOSUserBundle? There are BC in last versions.

Comment: It might be the reason. I updated the question. Is my user-bundle version incompatible with Symfony version?

Comment: Can you show us your User constructor?

Comment: There is no __construct() method in my User class.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You must drop your schema and recreate it again. Your salt column should be allowed to be null, because when using the `bcryp` algorithm it is indeed null as [the salt is directly included in the password (hash)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6832445/how-can-bcrypt-have-built-in-salts). Moreover here is the mapping declaration:

```
<field name="salt" column="salt" type="string" nullable="true" />
```

PS: And other advices, updates all bundle, clear the cache, the database and its data...

---

UPDATE:

Per dMedia, they changed the doctrine mapping in a recent update (Nov 2016)

https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/commit/a9a08c2daf3db38697a8bd4b6e00f42c9a33dd79#diff-36e2e6fca6f6ce7118933033f9ce8bff

Comment: Indeed. They changed doctrine mapping https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/commit/a9a08c2daf3db38697a8bd4b6e00f42c9a33dd79#diff-36e2e6fca6f6ce7118933033f9ce8bff. `php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force` did the job.