# Why jbcrypt does not need a salt at comparison

Tags: java, jbcrypt

I am currently looking for a librarly to store a salted, hashed password in a web app. I came across [mindrot's jbcrypt](http://www.mindrot.org/projects/jBCrypt/) and think it might be the right choice (also see https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/21184/safe-to-use-jbcrypt-and-recommend-it-to-my-organization). However, one thing is puzzling me a little bit about the code. Generally, hashing and salting a password is [done by calling](https://github.com/jeremyh/jBCrypt)

```
String hashed = BCrypt.hashpw(password, BCrypt.gensalt(12));
```

which uses a generated salt. To check a password later on, [here](https://github.com/jeremyh/jBCrypt) you can see (as well as on the mindrot page) that the

```
if (BCrypt.checkpw(candidate, hashed))
```

function is invoked with a plain text candidate. Also, in the coding of jbcrypt is says

```
public static boolean checkpw(String plaintext, String hashed)
```

Now my question is how can you compare a plain text password to a salted+hashed String without having the salt at comparison time (as it is not passed into the checkpw-function, obviously)?

Comment: Because hashpw returns a string containing the salt and the hash. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6832445/how-can-bcrypt-have-built-in-salts

Comment: Thanks - that answers my question very well. If you post an answer, I will mark it as correct.