# re: Postgres gen_salt: how can I later compare plaintext if the salt is random?

Tags: postgresql, security

I think the title says it all, but how does this work?

If a salt is generated randomly, wouldn't that make it impossible to later compare?

I'm following these docs: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgcrypto.html (F.25.2. Password Hashing Functions)

Answer (score 1):

Re: @erickson 's answer here [How can bcrypt have built-in salts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6832445/how-can-bcrypt-have-built-in-salts?rq=1)

it appears that the hashing algorithm used is recorded in the encrypted string that is produced from the hash action. Can anyone confirm this works the same way for postgres?

Comment: According to the documentation, yes. You need to do `SELECT pswhash = crypt('entered password', pswhash)` (where `pswhash` is a column/value in the database) to re-check passwords. (If you look closely, you can see that the "hash" is used in place of the `gen_salt()` call upon checking).