# Using PasswordEncoder - How salt is stored

Tags: java, spring

I'm using the following web security configuration for my Spring boot app:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired 
    private AccountRepository accountRepository;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/signup").permitAll()
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
                .logout().logoutUrl("/logout").logoutSuccessUrl("/login").deleteCookies("auth_code").invalidateHttpSession(true)
            .and()
            // We filter the api/signup requests
            .addFilterBefore(
                new JWTSignupFilter("/signup", authenticationManager(), accountRepository),
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            // We filter the api/login requests
            .addFilterBefore(
                new JWTLoginFilter("/login", authenticationManager()),
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            // And filter other requests to check the presence of JWT in
            // header
            .addFilterBefore(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(userDetailsServiceBean()),
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
            throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsServiceBean()).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsServiceBean() throws Exception {
        return new CustomUserDetailsService(accountRepository);
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        PasswordEncoder encoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        return encoder;
    }
}
```

As you can see, I use BCryptPasswordEncoder.

I have two problems:

1.Where is the salt for the BCryptPasswordEncoder stored ? According to my findings, it's random each time and it's stored somewhere in the database, but I didn't define any column for it. I'm confused over how it works.

2.I have a Signup filter:

```
public class JWTSignupFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {

    private AccountRepository accountRepository;

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    public JWTSignupFilter(String url, AuthenticationManager authManager,
            AccountRepository accountRepository) {
        super(new AntPathRequestMatcher(url, "POST"));
        setAuthenticationManager(authManager);
        this.accountRepository = accountRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest req,
            HttpServletResponse res) throws AuthenticationException,
            IOException, ServletException {

        CustomUserDetails creds = new ObjectMapper().readValue(
                req.getInputStream(), CustomUserDetails.class);

        if (accountRepository.findByUsername(creds.getUsername()) != null) {
            throw new AuthenticationException("Duplicate username") {
                private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
            };
        }

        CustomUserDetails userDetails = new CustomUserDetails(
                creds.getUsername(), creds.getPassword(), true, true, true,
                true,
                AuthorityUtils.commaSeparatedStringToAuthorityList("USER_ROLE"));

        accountRepository.save(userDetails);

        return getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(creds.getUsername(),
                        creds.getPassword()));
    }

    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest req,
            HttpServletResponse res, FilterChain chain, Authentication auth) {
        TokenAuthenticationService.addAuthentication(res, auth.getName());
    }
}
```

As you can see I create a new UserDetails and save it in the account repository.

If I encode the password while creating the `UserDetails` object, it would create not the same password as when logging in. (the econded passowrds are different) I think this should be because of the different salts being used.

Any idea how I can fix this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bcrypt [*includes batteries*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6833165/315306): the text that is typically saved in the database contains both the salt and the number of iterations. There are [online generators](https://www.dailycred.com/article/bcrypt-calculator) that can show it. For example, given the secret `P@ssw0rd` here is how it is serialized (4 iterations):

```
$2a$04$tpwXnhoO89cja8UZw3.hpulcAGzL1ps5cqzTLubh60csfEwna4N3W
$2a$04$VuLYo3y8e1ZITJPgW8LliOzdRa220D0frl5oSPQeFxAOlmvmsTCsK
$2a$04$bkChnYI84W3P3DW8YZrQc.yarPrW9kCDRAEp8ZKlap2BiO2Y.ThNa
...
```

Quoting [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6833165/315306)

> - `2a` identifies the bcrypt algorithm version
> - `04` is the cost factor; 2<sup>4</sup> iterations of the key derivation function are used
> - `vI8aWBnW3fID.ZQ4/zo1G.q1lRps.9cGLcZEiGDMVr5yUP1KUOYTa` is the salt and the cipher text, concatenated and encoded in a modified Base-64. The first 22 characters decode to a 16-byte value for the salt. The remaining characters are cipher text to be compared for authentication.

Comment: When a user signs up, the passed in password gets hashed and stored in a db. The next time user logs in, a password is passed in and hashed and compare with the already stored password. But, the salts are going to be different and the comparison fails. How does this work ?

Comment: The point is that the stored hash is never compared against as-is. You use something like [`BCrypt.checkpw`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/crypto/bcrypt/BCrypt.html#checkpw-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-)