# Symfony / FOSuserBundle : salt are null?

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, symfony-3.4

I'm using :

- Symfony 3.4
- FOSUserBundle 2

FOSuserbundle is well installed and works like a charm. I noticed that in my database, in the users table, the column "salt" is always empty :

[image]

Below is an extract from my security.yml file :

```
security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: bcrypt
```

For the record, I added the 2 users with the command "fos:user:create".

Is this normal ?

Comment: More info about bcrypt here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6832445/how-can-bcrypt-have-built-in-salts

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes this is normal, because with using `bcrypt` the salt is contained in the hashed password.

Reference: https://php.net/manual/password.constants.php#constant.password-bcrypt

> *salt* (string) - to manually provide a salt to use when hashing the
>   password. Note that this will override and prevent a salt from being
>   automatically generated.
>
> If omitted, a random salt will be generated by password_hash() for
>   each password hashed. This is the intended mode of operation and as of
>   PHP 7.0.0 the salt option has been deprecated.

---

You can see the behavior in the [source](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/d95bd92eb23d113b54830a6e98bc154c7da635a9/Util/PasswordUpdater.php#L43):

```
// FOSUserBundle/Util/PasswordUpdater.php [Line 43]

if ($encoder instanceof BCryptPasswordEncoder) {
    $user->setSalt(null);
}
```