# Bcrypt encryption different every time with same input

Tags: go

Using `golang.org/x/crypto/bcrypt` and GORM (http://gorm.io/docs/) I'm trying to encrypt a password. The problem is that every encryption of it is different every time, so it can never match the one in the database.

```
var result []string

password := []byte(data.Password)
encryptedPassword, err := bcrypt.GenerateFromPassword(password, bcrypt.DefaultCost) // different every time

db.Where(&User{Username: strings.ToLower(data.Username)}).First(&user).Pluck("password", &result)
encryptionErr := bcrypt.CompareHashAndPassword(encryptedPassword, []byte(result[0]))

if encryptionErr == nil { // passwords match! }
```

I have confirmed that the input is the same every time and that the password given from the database is correct.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you actually getting an error that passwords don't match from `CompareHashAndPassword`, or is your concern just that the `GenerateFromPassword` output is different each time?

Comment: Yeah I'm getting the error that they don't match, even when the input is the same.

Comment: I can only suggest re-checking that the inputs are, in fact, byte-for-byte identical. I have used this bcrypt library many times, and have never had any issue. The bytes returned by `GenerateFromPassword` will be different every time because it includes a random salt for security, but the salt is included in the output and does not interfere with password validation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [bcrypt hash algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt), by design, generates a different encrypted string every time you call it (it is [salted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography))).  If you have a plaintext password you want to check, and ciphertext in the database, you should be able to pass those two things to `bcrypt.CompareHashAndPassword`.  Adapting your code:

```
var result []string
db.Where(&User{Username: strings.ToLower(data.Username)})
        .First(&user)
        .Pluck("password", &result)

encryptionErr := bcrypt.CompareHashAndPassword([]byte(result[0]), []byte(data.Password))
```

You shouldn't need to call `bcrypt.GenerateFromPassword` again; as you note, it will generate a different encrypted password and it should be all but impossible to compare the two for equality.

Comment: I figured this out eventually myself. Thanks for the info though!

Answer (score 25):

> *The problem is that every encryption of it is different every time, so it can never match the one in the database.*

This is normal bcrypt behavior.

bcrypt returns a different hash each time because it incorporates a different random value into the hash. This is known as a "salt". It prevents people from attacking your hashed passwords with a "rainbow table", a pre-generated table mapping password hashes back to their passwords. The salt means that instead of there being one hash for a password, there's 2^16 of them. Too many to store.

The salt is stored as part of the hashed password. So `bcrypt.CompareHashAndPassword(encryptedPassword, plainPassword)` can encrypt `plainPassword` using the same salt as `encryptedPassword` and compare them.

See [this answer for more information](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6833165/14660) and Dustin Boswell's excellent [*Storing User Passwords Securely: hashing, salting, and Bcrypt*](https://web.archive.org/web/20190501051230/http://dustwell.com:80/how-to-handle-passwords-bcrypt.html).

> *What am I doing wrong here?*

You're trying to compare the generated *hashed* password with the stored *hashed* password. At least I certainly hope it's the hashed password that's stored in the database.

What you want instead is to compare the stored hashed password with the plain password the user entered. `bcrypt.CompareHashAndPassword` will then use the stored hashed password's salt to hash the plain password and compare.

```
// Normally this comes from user input and is *never* stored
plainPassword := "supersekret"

// The encrypted password is stored in the database
db.Where(&User{Username: strings.ToLower(data.Username)}).First(&user).Pluck("password", &result)
encryptedPassword := []byte(result[0])

// Check if the stored encrypted password matches "supersekret"
encryptionErr := bcrypt.CompareHashAndPassword(encryptedPassword, plainPassword)
if encryptionErr == nil {
    fmt.Println("Greetings Professor Falken")
} else {
    fmt.Println(encryptionErr)
}
```