# How to verify the password

Tags: go, passwords

In this code, the first function is `Findaccount()` that will find the email address in the database and the password that is present as a hash. So the `CompareHashAndPassword()` compares the hash and password.

Now in the `handler.go` file I have a function called `loginData()` that will allow the user to log in. I have a problem here. I called `database.Findaccount(email, password, hash)` function but it just verifies an email address and does not verify the
**correct password**, and give me the `false` message.

But if I call the function like this `database.Findaccount(email, "1234", hash)`, it verifies both email and password.

How to solve this problem because I won't be able to remember each password.

**db.go**

```
func Findaccount(myEmail, myPassword, hash string) bool {
    collection := Connect.Database("WebApp2").Collection("dataStored")
    if err := collection.FindOne(context.TODO(), bson.M{"email": myEmail}).Decode(&Account); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Enter the correct email or password")
    }
    err := bcrypt.CompareHashAndPassword([]byte(hash), []byte(myPassword))
    return err == nil
}
```

**handler.go**

```
func HashPassword(password string) (string, error) {
    bytes, err := bcrypt.GenerateFromPassword([]byte(password), 14)
    return string(bytes), err
}

func loginData(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    email := r.FormValue("email")
    password := r.FormValue("password")
    hash, _ := HashPassword(password)
    match := database.Findaccount(email, password, hash) // here is a problem
    if match == false {
        fmt.Println("false")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("true")
    }
}
```

Comment: You should take `hash` from the `Account`

Comment: Here is the hash `$2a$04$28kZ/RY.BhGyWQvWPAngduAhoZPjrsyE6zEDCufu1gClsHpCyXJeW`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per [documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/crypto/bcrypt#CompareHashAndPassword), this is the func schema of `bycrypt.CompareHashAndPassword()`:

```golang
func CompareHashAndPassword(hashedPassword, password []byte) error
```

To use that, you need to place the `hashedPassword` (which is the hashed password that you stored in the db) as the 1st parameter of the function call.

And then okace the `password` from request param as the value of 2nd parameter.

```golang
func loginData(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    email := r.FormValue("email")
    password := r.FormValue("password")
    match := database.Findaccount(email, password)
    if match == false {
        fmt.Println("false")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("true")
    }
}

func Findaccount(myEmail, myPassword string) bool {
    collection := Connect.Database("WebApp2").Collection("dataStored")
    if err := collection.FindOne(context.TODO(), bson.M{"email": myEmail}).Decode(&Account); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Enter the correct email or password")
    }
    err := bcrypt.CompareHashAndPassword([]byte(Account.Password), []byte(myPassword))
    return err == nil
}
```

See on the `Findaccount()`, the first param of statement `bcrypt.CompareHashAndPassword()` is filled by `Account.Password` which is the hashed password stored on the db.

Comment: a little bit of salt would be appropriate for that recipe, no ?

Comment: @mh-cbon if during the registration process the password is hashed with a salt, then the same salt should be included during the login. from OP question, I've made an assumption that salt is not used at all. might need more details to confirm that.

Comment: yes, i agree. I certainly wanted to open OP eyes about what could be done next. the answer does answer OP, thus, i have plused it.

Comment: @mh-cbon bcrypt includes the salt automatically

Comment: @zerkms  had no idea it did that.... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6832445/how-can-bcrypt-have-built-in-salts thank you