# If I change my server bcrypt can remember salt and decrypt Password,How can do that?

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption, bcrypt, salt

I want to deploy my program to another server.  Can my script decrypt all passwords of my customers in database correctly?

```
//old server
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
const salt = bcrypt.genSalt();
password = bcrypt.hash("password", salt);

//new server 
const auth = bcrypt.compare(password, "password")
```

How can BCrypt decrypt passwords with a variable salt that is generated randomly?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can bcrypt have built-in salts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6832445/how-can-bcrypt-have-built-in-salts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BCrypt hashes are stored in one of two forms.

The more common is [Modular Crypt Format](https://github.com/ademarre/binary-mcf) and has the form...

```
$2y$10$kV7kssmFuFOydBewIp9ele8GMkWGDPpte6jGGDAabpsBmxtzWxfZW
```

Where:

- `$` is a delimiter
- `2` indicates the algorithm is BCrypt
- `y` is the version of BCrypt
- 10 is the cost
- `kV7kssmFuFOydBewIp9ele` is the salt
- `8GMkWGDPpte6jGGDAabpsBmxtzWxfZW` is the hash.

A more modern alternative is [PHC string format](https://github.com/P-H-C/phc-string-format/blob/master/phc-sf-spec.md) which makes it more obvious which parts correspond to which values:

```
$bcrypt$v=98$r=10$cIF1Ev2ATA6/iYv4kddXCQ$qcrDoGjsiB2eLq1/vCZWiAZ8bEs4+Qs
```

In both cases, the string persisted to your database is completely portable and contains everything necessary to compare a candidate password: The hash, salt, cost, algorithm name, and algorithm version.