# php cannot login

Tags: php, mysql, hash, authentication

I have this set of codes

```
$user = htmlentities($_POST['user']);
$pass = htmlentities($_POST['pass']);

function sha512($str) { return hash("sha512", $str); }
$pass = sha512($pass);

$tzlogin = sprintf("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user='%s' AND pass='%s'",
mysql_real_escape_string($user), mysql_real_escape_string($pass));

$tzlogged = mysql_query($tzlogin, $config) or die(mysql_error());

if (mysql_num_rows($tzlogged) == 0){
    header (sprintf("Location: ./login.php?status=error"));
} else {
    if (isset($_POST['tz-remember'])){
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT uid FROM users WHERE user='".$user."'", $config);
        $id = mysql_fetch_row($query);
        foreach($id as $uid){
            setcookie('uid', $uid, time() + 60*60*24*30*11, '/', '.localhost');
        }
        header (sprintf("Location: ./index.php"));
    } else {
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT uid FROM users WHERE user='".$user."'", $config);
        $id = mysql_fetch_row($query);
        foreach($id as $uid){
            $_SESSION['uid'] = $uid;
        }
        header (sprintf("Location: ./index.php"));
    }
}
```

its all correct i think because earlier i was able to login properly but suddenly i am not i encrypted the password into a hash format while registration and while logging in i again first encrypted it then selected and when i looked carefully the inserted data in the database is missing some lines while the data entered is a bit longer like i enter a password test now the inserted data is

"ee26b0dd4af7e749aa1a8ee3c10ae9923f618980772e473f8819a5d4940e0db27ac185f8a0e1d5f84f88bc887fd67b143732"

while the posted data is

"ee26b0dd4af7e749aa1a8ee3c10ae9923f618980772e473f8819a5d4940e0db27ac185f8a0e1d5f84f88bc887fd67b143732c304cc5fa9ad8e6f57f50028a8ff" why is that so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SHA-512 generates a 512-bit hash value, which can be represented in CHAR(128).

you can see other types of sha in here: [What data type to use for hashed password field and what length?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247304/mysql-what-data-type-to-use-for-hashed-password-field-and-what-length)

Answer (score 1):

Your database field is set to 100 characters. Increase the length to 128.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the password field in the database is too short.

Please post the result of `SHOW CREATE TABLE users`.