# PHP MySQL Binary select

Tags: php, mysql, binary, sha1

I have been searching around for an hour and I cannot get this to work.

I have a table called `user` with 2 columns `username varchar(64)` and `password binary(20)`. I am using a SHA1 encryption, because I want to make this quick and dirty.

```
mysql> describe user;
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field    | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| username | varchar(64) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| password | binary(20)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

When I want to authenticate a user's password, I am running in to a bit of trouble. I am not getting the resulting password in binary. Any suggestions? Thanks.

```
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$password = sha1(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']));
$binPass = pack("H*", $password);
$query = "SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE `username` = '$username' AND `password` = $binPass;";
```

Comment: Why are you storing it as a binary blob instead of a hex string?  You already have it, may as well use it.  Also, this is an obligatory mention of bcrypt/pbkdf2/scrypt/partridges in pear trees as better options than unsalted SHA1.

Comment: I am basing my password storage off of this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/247627/1762224).

Answer (score 0):

There is no point in calculating the checksum of a sql escaped password. You want to calculate the checksum of the raw password, and because you're using binary data in your query, it must be escaped using `mysql_real_escape_string` before you include it in the query or you will get unexpected results.

```
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$password = sha1($_POST['password']);
$binPass = mysql_real_escape_string(pack("H*", $password));
$query = "SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE `username` = '$username' AND `password` = '$binPass'"
```

You'll save 50% of the space by storing it in binary form in the database, but the performance increase will be minimal at best. You should consider just storing the hexadecimal checksum in the database instead.