# MySQL SHA() doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, hash

So basically I encrypted password in my registration form like so:

```
    $query = "INSERT INTO users(first_name, last_name, email, password, 
                         username) VALUES ('$fn', '$ln', '$em', SHA('$pw1'), '$un')";
```

Now the password is hashed, but when I try to use it in my login script it doesn't want to work and function mysql_num_rows returns 0.

```
    <?php
                ob_start();
                    //If login button is pressed
                    if(isset($_POST['submitted'])){
                        //Username clean up
                        if(preg_match('%^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{6,20}$%', stripslashes(trim($_POST['username'])))){
                            $u = escape_data($_POST['username']);
                        } else {
                            $u = FALSE;
                            echo '<p><font color="red" size="+1">Please enter valid username</font></p>';
                        }

                        //Password clean up
                        if(preg_match('%^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{6,20}$%', stripslashes(trim($_POST['password'])))){
                            $p = escape_data($_POST['password']);
                        } else {
                            $p = FALSE;
                            echo '<p><font color="red" size="+1">Please enter valid password</font></p>';
                        }

                        //Check if both matched
                        if($u && $p){
                            $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$u' AND password=SHA('$p')";
                            $result = mysql_query($query);
                            $count = mysql_num_rows($result);
                            $row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM);
                            if($count != 0){
                                $_SESSION['username'] = $row[1];
                                $_SESSION['password'] = $row[3];
                                header("Location: login_confirmed.php");
                            } else {
                                echo "Wrong username or password!";
                            }
                        } 
                    }
                    ob_end_flush();
                ?>
```

Comment: What's the type of your password field?

Comment: have you checked the database for inserted value and retrieved value ?

Comment: WARNING: SHA is NOT an encryption algorithm!  It is a hashing algorithm!

Comment: `password`, which you used for your column name is a reserved word which tend to create myriad of problems if used as column names. Ensure you have data inserted before trying anything else. If you do, debug your script using `echo`'s. You'll profit way more if you fix this problem yourself instead of asking for help.

Comment: I'd also be careful about selecting all columns (`*`) and then setting variables by indexed results - database structures can change... and the obligatory "`mysql`" is deprecated warning, too.

Comment: Yes, the password encrypted value excisted in MySQL table. Also note if I would remove SHA function from registration form and from login script, so it would just insert a password in the MySQL table(not the encrypted one) then it would work.

Comment: to extend @RussellUhl comment. difference between hashing and encryption: hashed text can't be recovered back (usually) while encrypted text can be recovered [text = decrypt(encrypt(text))]

Comment: Use sha1('$password')

Comment: @N.B., `PASSWORD` is a builtin function, but it is not a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reserved-words.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably because of your password field type. Is your password field `VARCHAR`? How long is it? It seems to me that `SHA` is generating a string longer than it is allowed by the field so it gets cutoff when it is stored and it does match when you regenerate it to check.

[MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html#function_sha1) says that you need 40 characters to store the output of `SHA`.

> Calculates an SHA-1 160-bit checksum for the string, as described in
>   RFC 3174 (Secure Hash Algorithm). The value is returned as a string of
>   40 hex digits, or NULL if the argument was NULL. One of the possible
>   uses for this function is as a hash key.

Comment: Amazing, it worked. I had varchar(30) set table. I wouldn't figure it out. Big thank you for you! Just amazing.

Comment: Why would you have varchar(30) at all? Do you know what varchars are and how they work?

Comment: I thought, that passwords are usually like around 30 characters, but I forgot that SHA function makes the string 40 character long.

Comment: @user2564336, cf. [MySQL: what data type to use for hashed password field and what length?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/247304/mysql-what-data-type-to-use-for-hashed-password-field-and-what-length/247627#247627)