# Password hashing doesn't work

Tags: php, hash, sha

I'm inserted some users into the MySQL database

```
$register_query = " INSERT INTO user ( name, password, permission_id) 
VALUES ( '$username', SHA('$password_01'), '1' ) ";
```

I wants to read the user table for logging in

```
require_once('initializing.php');

class DbPlus extends MySQLDatabaseConnection{

public $database;

function __construct()
{
    $this->database = parent::connection();
}

public function reading_table($table, $query, $where = null, $limit = null, $order = null){

    $query = "SELECT {$query} FROM {$table}";
    if ( isset($where) ) {
        $query .= " WHERE {$where}";

    }
    if ( isset($order) ){
        $query .= " ORDER BY {$order}";
    }
    if ( isset($limit) ) {
        $query .= " LIMIT {$limit}";
    }

    // $data = $this->database->query($query);
    $data = $this->database->query($query);

    $rows = array();
    while ( $row = $data->fetch_object() ) {
        $rows[] = $row;

    }

    return $rows;
    }
}

$dbplus = new DbPlus;

$login_qry_slct = "id,name,password,permission_id";
$login_qry_whr = "name ='test' AND password = SHA('test')";
$result = $dbplus->reading_table('user', $login_qry_slct, $login_qry_whr );
var_dump($result);
```

For testing purpose I inserted `name=test`, and `password=test`. I did it in two ways, with and without SHA(). When I inserted the password 'test' without hashing, the select query works fine (note: it is for testing purposes) and returns the non hashed test user.

```
 $login_qry_whr = "name ='test' AND password = 'test'";
```

But when I using SHA

```
$login_qry_whr = "name ='test' AND password = SHA('test')";
```

Returns `array(0) { }` (note: there is hashed version saved in in the user table too)

What am I doing wrong with SHA()?

Comment: try to do like this '{SHA($password)}'.

Comment: you should use sha for secure password, use salt and then crypt the password and save, also crypt in PHP will be good

Comment: What is the 'password' column length and type in the database? check if the column length is enough for the hashed value and no trimming occurs

Comment: -1 for the function read() which makes a giggerish out of fine SQL language. Trying to save yourself typing of a few KEY words you are spoiling whole code

Comment: possibly duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17547738/mysql-sha-doesnt-work

Comment: @GRSEV varchar and it is set for 40.

Comment: @user3442100 no duplicated, I read this post before and checked the column type

Comment: @YourCommonSense I edited the function, can you take back the -1? Thank you

Comment: Gods. I wouldn't -1 for just a *name*. It's the very function and its purpose itself

Comment: Also see Openwall's [PHP password hashing framework](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/) (PHPass). Its portable and hardened against a number of common attacks on user passwords. The guy who wrote the framework (SolarDesigner) is the same guy who wrote [John The Ripper](http://www.openwall.com/john/) and sits as a judge in the [Password Hashing Competition](http://password-hashing.net/). So he knows a thing or two about attacks on passwords.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

sha1(password) instead of sha(password).

Orelse try this one,password_hash() function or crypt function.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

Hope this works for you.

Comment: Try removing the single quotes from this, SHA('$password_01').. Use as SHA($password_01)

Comment: Chinju I removed the quotes, got errors Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_object() on a non-object in D:\XAMPP\htdocs\xxx\includes\dbplus.php on line 31

Comment: Try this, $register_query = " INSERT INTO user ( name, password, permission_id) 
VALUES ( '".$username."', '".SHA($password_01)."', 1 ) ";

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function SHA() in D:\XAMPP\htdocs\xxx\includes\adduser.php on line 15

Comment: Chinju Inserted fine with sha1, but selection returns empty array too  $login_qry_whr = "name='$username' AND password={sha1('$password')}";

Comment: Try this,  $login_qry_whr = "name ='".$username."' AND password = '".SHA1($password)."'";

Comment: Chinju it works, thank you. Can you explain me where did I the problem? sha() or the quotes? Thank you

Comment: The problem was both. Because i don think there is a function sha in PHP and the string values without quotes was not accepting in the query. Thats y i changed it.

Comment: But I thought in the select query I can use sha()

Comment: Hmmm.. We will have a research on it to check it out. Have a great day.

Answer (score 0):

Please please don't use SHA* for hashing passwords, instead use a slow key-derivation function like BCrypt or PBKDF2 with a cost factor. The verification cannot be done in an SQL statement directly (because of the salt), so you have to do it in your PHP code:

```
// Hash a new password for storing in the database.
// The function automatically generates a cryptographically safe salt.
$hashToStoreInDb = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

// Check if the hash of the entered login password, matches the stored hash.
// The salt and the cost factor will be extracted from $existingHashFromDb.
$isPasswordCorrect = password_verify($password, $existingHashFromDb);
```

Answer (score -1):

I never ran into problems like this by hashing the password in PHP by using the native hash() function.

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE username = 'test' AND password = '" . hash('sha256', $password) . "'";
?>
```

Documentation: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php