# What data-types and sizes should I use to store PBKF2(sha256) Hashes and base64 salts in mysql table?

Tags: php, mysql, database, pbkdf2

I decided to secure my users passwords with PBKF2(Password-Based Key Derivation Function) as mentioned in [this article](https://defuse.ca/php-pbkdf2.htm)

What my problem is that I couldn't find which **MySQL data type** should I used to store these generated **hashes and base64 salts** and what length those should be.

Thank You

Comment: [see this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/247304/mysql-what-data-type-to-use-for-hashed-password-field-and-what-length)

Comment: @palerdot Thanks friend I searched everywhere on SO to find an answer before ask this question.But didn't found this article.