# Difference between BINARY(16) and CHAR(32) when storing MD5 in database

Tags: mysql, sql, binary, md5

Based on various recommendations such as [What data type to use for hashed password field and what length?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247304/mysql-what-data-type-to-use-for-hashed-password-field-and-what-length), I could store md5 as either CHAR(32) or BINARY(16).  But when I do so using BINARY(16), the stored value is identical to the first 16 characters of the CHAR(32) stored results as well as the first 16 characters of the `SELECT MD5()` results.  What are the significance of the later 16 characters, and is their lack of presence in the binary column resulting in lost data?

```
CREATE  TABLE test (id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, value VARCHAR(6), md5_char CHAR(32) NOT NULL, md5_binary BINARY(16) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (id)) ENGINE = InnoDB;
INSERT INTO test(value,md5_char,md5_binary) VALUES("one!",md5("one!"),md5("one!"));
INSERT INTO test(value,md5_char,md5_binary) VALUES("two%",md5("two%"),md5("two%"));
INSERT INTO test(value,md5_char,md5_binary) VALUES("three~",md5("three~"),md5("three~"));
SELECT value,md5(value),md5_char,md5_binary FROM test;
DROP TABLE test;

+--------+----------------------------------+----------------------------------+------------------+
| value  | md5(value)                       | md5_char                         | md5_binary       |
+--------+----------------------------------+----------------------------------+------------------+
| one!   | 633c8403325f1cf963809e6eb224d77e | 633c8403325f1cf963809e6eb224d77e | 633c8403325f1cf9 |
| two%   | 48bbec047b4451a2018e0f652807b7d0 | 48bbec047b4451a2018e0f652807b7d0 | 48bbec047b4451a2 |
| three~ | fee453bb4eb68dcdfee07575e75c8cc5 | fee453bb4eb68dcdfee07575e75c8cc5 | fee453bb4eb68dcd |
+--------+----------------------------------+----------------------------------+------------------+
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Currently you are losing half of the checksum when using `BINARY(16)`. When you store an MD5 checksum in `BINARY(16)` you should store it as binary data, *not* encoded in hexadecimal. That is:

```
INSERT INTO test (md5_binary) VALUES(UNHEX(md5("one!")));
```

You can use the HEX function to encode it into hex again if you want to eye-ball compare it with another checksum:

```
SELECT HEX(md5_binary) FROM test;
```

The benefit of using BINARY to store the checksum instead of hexadecimal text is that half the storage is needed.

Comment: Thanks Joni,  Similar, Blowfish-based bcrypt requires CHAR(60) to store it.  Could I use BINARY(30) if I use `UNHEX()`?

Comment: The storage benefit is unrelated to the data type.  You could store hexadecimal in binary, and un-hexed data in a char column.

Comment: But will binary always require exactly half the digits of char?

Comment: Just realized your post states "half the storage is needed".  Thanks

Comment: @Andomar, storing binary data in a CHAR column is not recommended: the database will then interpret the data as having a particular character encoding, and you may corrupt the data unless you know what you are doing (i.e. use a single-byte encoding and a binary collation)

Comment: @user1032531, does bcrypt produce a hex-encoded string? If it does, you can store it in 50% the space by storing it as binary.

Comment: It'd actually end up being an even bigger space saving than half, would it not? Since the `char` field would most likely use some sort of character encoding also, like `utf8mb4` which would be 4 bytes per character. So you could be using only 12.5% of the space with `binary` over `char` in the best case.

Comment: Yes, it depends on the encoding. MySQL has traditionally defaulted to latin1 which uses one byte per character, but you can always change it.

Comment: I'm slightly confused, isn't hex 4 bits, and here binary(1) is 8 bits, why is it that mysql is representing binary(x) as the number of bytes and not bits?