# How To Check If A Password Is A Hash - PHP

Tags: php, validation, hash, passwords

I have a user class that does some simple validation. I want to store all passwords as hashes using phpass. However, i dont want it to be the job of the User class to set the hash, This is the job of some other function. So if i have a simple function called setPassword how can i make sure the password is a hash. Does is_binary work?? I am not comparing hashes here i just simple want to make sure the password is a hash..shouldnt matter what kind md5..sha1...blah. I JUST WANT TO MAKE SURE THE PASSWORD IS A HASH.

example:

```
class User
{
    private password = NULL;
    private $errors = array();

    public function setPassword($password)
    {
        // make sure password is a hash...pseudo code
        if (!password_is_hash($password))
        {
            $this->errors[] = 'Invalid password';
            return $this;
        }
        $this->password = $password;
        return $this;
    } 

    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean, "is a hash"? `md5('foo')` will spit out the hash `acbd18db4cc2f85cedef654fccc4a4d8`, which could also be a perfectly valid password on its own... Technically **ANY** 32char hex string is an md5 hash, though you can't tell what it's a hash OF.

Comment: Ya i guess is there a way to make sure the password isnt something like, dog, coming in or going out of the database? I guess a user could post that as there password. most wont..I need the setPassword function to make sure whats going in and coming out of the database is a hashed password. So not myfavoritepassword.

Comment: Generally, hashing of passwords would be part of *authentication* and not the domain object. I would pass in *only* a hashed password.

Comment: you don't compare passwords. you take whatever the user gives you and hash it with your chosen hash algorithm. If the hash you get from the user inputs matches the hash you've saved in the database, then they've provided the right password.

Comment: I understand, thats what i plan on doing. All passwords will be hashed and stored as a hash using phpass. Is there no way through simple validation that the password being set is indeed a hash. Lets say the hashing function fails and somehow passes the password unhashed..I want setPassword to catch this and throw an error. And if somehow it got into the database unhashed...not sure how, this would also throw an error when retrieving the hashed password from the db

Comment: You're inventing all this because you believe there's no way to know if a hashing function completes successfully?

Comment: I think your issue is where you way "Lets say the hashing function fails".  If it fails, it won't fail silently.  The hashing function would throw an error.  It would never just return the password back.  Unless you're writing your OWN hashing function.  Which, protip:  DON'T.  There are plenty of free and VERY SECURE versions available.  If you already ARE using an existing version, there's no reason to think that the hashing library is any more likely to mysteriously "fail" than any other part of your program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have said hashes are strings and although (under conditions) you could say that an md5 or sha1 is always n characters you cannot guarantee that the given string is a hash.

If what you want now is compare the user provided password with the hash saved in the db you could fetch the saved hash from the database and then hash the provided string with the same function used to create the saved hash and make sure they are equal and authenticate.

Comment: Ok, thanks i was hoping there was something that set a hashed password apart from a string, but i guess that doesnt make to much sense.

Answer (score 14):

I'm not sure if it's always correct/safe but you can use the `password_get_info` function. If the method can't guess the algorithm, we can assume that the string is not a hash.

```
function password_is_hash($password)
{
    return password_get_info($password)['algoName'] !== 'unknown';
}
```

This doesn't work for simple algorithms like sha1 or md5.

Answer (score 0):

All hashes is just strings. So you can't check exactly if it is hash. MD5 hash looks like `a23b34c45d56a23b34c45d56a23b34c4` and you can't distinguish it from `myrealreallooooongpassword111222`

Comment: what if u know what hashing algorithm is being used? Like from this post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/247304/mysql-what-data-type-to-use-for-hashed-password-field-and-what-length. I believe phpass uses BCrypt.

Comment: @user2707535 - I don't think you've understood the answer. I can get the output of any hashing algorithm and just type it in the password box. How can you know where it came from?

Comment: I think you have smth screwed logic here. Can you explain big picture? I can't imagine situation where i need to check if given string is a hash or not.

Answer (score 0):

I am not very much sure what are you trying to do  but  i think why you are checking if the password is hash or not.

If you making it hash using any function/library then you can check in that function whether hashing completed successfully or not.

Apart from this you cannot identify that whether a string is hash(ed) or not  because it's a string.