# Data type to store phphash password

Tags: php, mysql, security, hash, cryptography

I am using http://www.openwall.com/phpass/ to hash passwords, and do it as:

```
$t_hasher = new passwordhash(8, FALSE);
$hash =$t_hasher->HashPassword('myPassword');
```

A typical hash looks like `$2a$08$xKcZiTBgnoJ2z/aXg2K7m.0roI4gMDO3VSYmBAH/nYAYjPNBfo1Lq`

What data type should I use for the SQL table to store $hash?

Comment: you can use varchar field type to store in DB

Comment: Please take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/247304/mysql-what-data-type-to-use-for-hashed-password-field-and-what-length - it looks similar to your question

Comment: Closed as a duplicate?  I didn't ask about storing a Bcrypt hash, but something by the phphash class by openwall.

Comment: @user1032531 Your example hash is a Bcrypt hash.

Answer (score 0):

To be future proof and don't rely on any implementation use a `VARBINARY` or `TINYBLOB` (something that can hold up to 255 bytes and is of variable length). This is also recommended in the [PHP manual itself](http://www.php.net/manual/en/password.constants.php).

Comment: I am currently using binary(60).  Is this the correct size?

Comment: That's fine as long as you don't change the algorithm that generates your hash. For instance, you might update to a better hashing algorithm in the future which might require 61 bytes and now you'll have alter your table. The type `BINARY` without any number equals to `BINARY(255)`.

Comment: Would char(256) be better, or stick with binary(60)?

Comment: Definitely stick to a binary type, simply to ensure that the encoding is exactly the same as generated by the hashing algorithm and not tampered with by your DBMS system.

Comment: I might one day update the phphash library, and unbeknownst to me, the algorithms have been changed.  Maybe change from binary(60) to binary(256)?

Comment: Go for a variable data type (e.g. `VARBINARY` or `TINYBLOB`) otherwise it might be filled with zero bytes and your hashes are corrupt (I edited my answer to reflect this problem).

Comment: Hi Fleshgrinder.  You might be 100% correct, but this answer doesn't align with the officially approved answer....

Comment: Which *officially approved answer*? Check the linked PHP manual page and feel free to check out how hashes grew over the last decades. Of course your `BINARY(60)` is enough for your current hash (I already said that), but it's simply not future proof.

Comment: Related to second comment, the type `BINARY` without any number IS NOT equal to `BINARY(255)` on my server, but `BINARY(1)`.