# Insert new row with SH1 encrypted value - "Function does not exist"

Tags: mysql

I tried using this syntax inside mysql command line:

```
insert into users (username, pass, firstname, lastname) values ('admin', sh1('0000'), 'foo', 'bar');
```

for inserting new row into my users table, unfortuantly I've got the error 1305: FUNCTION users.SH1 does not exist.

so why I'm getting this error? and how to fix the problem? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error message tells you, that function `SH1` does not exists but your posted code uses the (existing) function `sha1`.

Please check your original code ;)

Comment: I'm trying to use the MySQL standard SH1 function, I'm not doing php programming, I'm just using mysql command line.

Comment: There is NO SH1-function.

Comment: so how to do for storing SH1 encrypted passwords?

Comment: USe `SHA1` instead of `SH1`. There's an `A`, can you see it?

Comment: yeah, that's true, I was forgetting the 'A', now when I fixed the command I'm getting other error: 1406: data too long for column 'pass'? what should I do now?

Comment: Your `pass`-column should be `varchar(40)`.

Comment: I understand now, my pass column is varchar(20), that really helps, thank you very much.

Comment: Cf. [MySQL: what data type to use for hashed password field and what length?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/247304/mysql-what-data-type-to-use-for-hashed-password-field-and-what-length/247627#247627)