# MySQL: Data type and length for hashed password?

Tags: mysql, hash, passwords

Possible duplicate: [MySQL: what data type to use for hashed password field and what length?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247304/mysql-what-data-type-to-use-for-hashed-password-field-and-what-length)

To save password, I am trying to use `SHA2()` in MySQL.

But when saving the hashed password `SHA2(CONCAT(pwd_salt, pwd), 512)`, why does this need `binary(128)`, not `binary(64)`? (512 bit => 64 (=512/8) bytes).

I guess that MySQL might save the hashed data into string, not binary data.

When I put

```
SELECT SHA2('some password with random salt', 512);
```

, it gives 128 words like

```
414c33de702e93bad92529973d651c7e4c5811ebe4a7f74775386245c0cfbc2b
3cf57260a833a4a6ad923bb9e13c9f8da768ad4d435b90b54f2c4c75ee3b22e4
```

I tried

```
SELECT CAST(SHA2('some password with random salt', 512) AS BINARY(64));
```

But this just truncate the data into 64 words like

```
414c33de702e93bad92529973d651c7e4c5811ebe4a7f74775386245c0cfbc2b
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You might be interested by Bill Karwin's answer here to the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/247304/mysql-what-data-type-to-use-for-hashed-password-field-and-what-length. I am surprised this did not come up when you asked the question under possible duplicates.

Comment: I just overread some part. Sorry for the duplicate question.

Comment: It's fine. The problem was that the answer was plagiarized. It has been removed.