# MYSQL PASSWORD() TO MD5() Wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, md5, password-encryption

I have and old table for users.

Old insert example: `INSERT INTO user SET password = PASSWORD('qwerty')`

I need to import all users from the old table to WordPress users. How can I do it?

Comment: Totally unsafe method. I suggest you copy your entire DB and migrate it to the new platform, then setup a script that will ask your users to update their passwords, using up-to-date password storage methods, such as [**CRYPT_BLOWFISH**](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/36471) or PHP 5.5's [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function. For PHP < 5.5 use the [`password_hash() compatibility pack`](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat). Do not use MD5; it's old (*circa 1992*) and is considered broken.

Comment: AES_DECRYPT will probably work... I'm amazed you were using this :)

Comment: Actually, if you move your passwords over with a single pass of MD5, upon first login to newer version of Wordpress, it will actually salt and re-hash the users password. While this isn't the safest method, it is one available to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL's PASSWORD() function does a double-SHA1 hashing, which is not reversible. You cannot retrieve the original password.

To convert to a different hash function, you must ask your users to re-enter their password.

---

Further thought: I had an experience once to change the hash function for an application. I could not ask all the users to re-enter their password. So I had to write special code in the application to support both hash formats. When validating passwords on login, fetch the hashed password, [infer the hashing function from the length of the hash string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247304/mysql-what-data-type-to-use-for-hashed-password-field-and-what-length/247627#247627), and then perform the password validation in the application. When any user changed their password, of course store the hash using the new function. Eventually almost all users had unknowingly converted their password storage to the new function. Then I contacted just a few users to ask them to change their password.

This strategy works unless you have a required deadline for upgrading all password hashing, for example to comply with some security regulation. I had the advantage that the application was only an intranet application and there was no strict deadline.

Comment: Which is what I suggested to the OP. The question's title *"MYSQL PASSWORD() TO MD5() Wordpress"* and wanting to go from a safer method to an older/broken hashing method, made me skin shiver.

Comment: But even if they choose to convert to a stronger hash function, they still can't recover the original passwords.

Comment: I was "agreeing" with you about *"you must ask your users to re-enter their password"* ;)

Comment: Also, there are still legitimate uses for MD5, just not for password storage or other cases where you need it to be cryptographically secure.

Comment: Couldn't agree with you more ;)

Comment: Thanks! Re-enter password is great idea, but the number of users > 8 000. They will have discomfort on services :(