# How to generate a unique ID for a row with "name" and "date", to avoid duplicate entries?

Tags: php, mysql, rest

I have the following situation:

I'm using a REST API from a site to get a list of the last 50 sales for a user. For each sale it returns product name and the timestamp of the sale (and some other stuff like amount, etc).

I want to incrementally add new sales to my database, but I don't know how to avoid duplicate entries, because I'm not getting any sale ID or anything like that. I'm guessing that I have to combine the timestamp and product name to generate a unique hash for each sale, and use that as a primary key in my table.

Is that the correct way to do it, and how would I implement it in code? I'm using PHP.

Cheers

Comment: Why don't you just use an [autoincrement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/example-auto-increment.html) column for your PK; or if you want non-sequential values, use a [UUID](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid)

Comment: If you don't want to add an autoincrement integer (serial/id) you can generate a token from the concatenation of the product name and timestamp, as with SQL md5 function or PHP md5.

Comment: Autoincrement won't work, because you can't know if two sales are unique unless you compare both the timestamp and product name. Seems like sha1 or md5 is the way to go, but I need some details regarding the implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have a lot of options. You can create a UNIQUE INDEX on your table using both fields to avoid duplicity or generate a hash to identify them (`sha1($name.$timestamp)`, for example).

Comment: Any recommendation what data type and length should be the column in MySQL? TEXT, VARCHAR, etc?

Comment: VARCHAR AND DATETIME (OR TIMESTAMP)

Comment: Thanks, it worked just fine. For future reference, I looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/247304/what-data-type-to-use-for-hashed-password-field-and-what-length for the data types, and looks like CHAR(40) is the way to go with sha1. If you feel like it you can include this link in your answer. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**

Your problem is that you're deduplicating redundant data sent you by a service you don't control. (I misunderstood that in my earlier answer).

It seems you have product and timestamp for each sale.  Do you also have any other identifying information, such as store or register number?

Are the fifty items always the most recent fifty?  Are they presented in any useful order in the REST request -- e.g. oldest first?

If you get, say, three new rows and 47 duplicates, are the duplicates identical to the previously received items -- same time, product, amount, other stuff?

If that's the case, I would do the following.

Create the table with these columns and indexes.

```
    id BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT 
    inserttime DATETIME NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    repeats INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
    saletime   DATETIME
    item       VARCHAR(nn)
    amount     int
    description  (etc)
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
    UNIQUE INDEX (saletime,item, amount, description)
```

Then when you receive records from your REST interface, insert them as follows.

```
INSERT INTO table (saletime, item, amount, description)
            VALUES (?,?,?,?)
   ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE repeats=repeats+1
```

This will use MySQL's unique key setup to remove duplicates. At the same time it will let you know how often you are getting repeated data, and when you most recently got it.

You can always find out when the most recent sale took place with

```
SELECT MAX(saletime) FROM table
```

and your compound index will help satisfy that query.

**Don't use a SHA style hash of multiple columns for this purpose.** It's a notorious MySQL antipattern. That's because MySQL's indexes are BTREE (ordered) in their organization, whereas a hash is unordered.

Comment: Consider this case: I get a list of the last 50 sales for a user and add them all to the database (let's assume that at first I'm sure they don't exist, so I add them all) and each sale ends up with it's unique auto-incremented ID. Later I get a new list of the last 50 sales, but only 3 of those sales are new and the other 47 should already be in the database. How would the auto-increment column help me in this case? In other words, how to know if a certain sale already exists in the database?

Comment: Oh, I get it. You are deduplicating redundant data sent to you by some service you don't control.

Comment: Yes, exactly. It would be easy if their API returned a sale ID, but I just have to assume that two sales for a product can't happen in the same second. The volume of sales, in the most extreme cases is 50 per day, so I think I should be safe.