# Mysql Storing hash in varbinary and how to use it after in where clause example

Tags: mysql, varbinary

I am newbie in MySQL and I am quite confused en how to insert and after how to retrieve row using this hash in where clause in a varbinary type column.

```
/*sql*/
CREATE TABLE my_table(hash_column VARBINARY(32));

//php
$hash = "3cd63ba0e52e7c16316bd3b1d33a1bdbc6128fa55f4747c80ac4eab104a9f459";

//this seem to work ok because I can see new item in my_tabl
$sql = "INSERT INTO my_table (hash_column) VALUES ('$hash');


//there is my problem y have tried all this but got 0 result
$sql = "SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE hash_column  = '$hash'";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE hash_column  = HEX('$hash')";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE hash_column  = BINARY HEX('$hash')";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE hash_column  = BINARY '$hash'";
```

**SOLVED:**
With some ideas from @JuveLeo1906 and @Psi and this post [What data type to use for hashed password field and what length?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247304/what-data-type-to-use-for-hashed-password-field-and-what-length) that help me find the right solution.

Right solution here:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO my_table (hash_column) VALUES (UNHEX('$hash'));

$sql = "SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE hash_column  = UNHEX('$hash')";
```

Comment: why don't you store the hash in a `varchar` instead?

Comment: `select * from my_table where hash_column  = binary('$hash')` should work.

Comment: @Psi 1.To save space as I read several tips. 2.According to it says here is also faster http://blog.3234.net/20100609/hashbytes-varchar-vs-varbinary-performance/

Comment: @JuveLeo1906  I have tried now BINARY('$hash')  and not work  :(

Comment: You don't save space that way, because your hash value is still using 2 bytes for each binary byte because the character codes are stored, not the binary value: `set varbin = '0d0a'` results in a four byte binary containing 0x30443041 (the char codes for "0", "d", "0" and "a"). You should set it this way then: `set varbin = 0x0d0a` without any quotation marks. Try comparing `WHERE hash_column = cast( '$hash' as varbinary )`

Comment: Thank's for you time @Psi but cast( '$hash' as varbinary ) got to me an error Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; (I using PDO)

Comment: I just came to another suspicion... did you check for lowercase/uppercase mismatch? (Again: You don't save space at the moment)

Comment: @MTK. I believe your issue might be with your column definition, try increasing the length.

Comment: Not. All hashes are lowercase.

Comment: **SOLVED:** ... With your ideas I have reached the next solution: using UNHEX('$hash') when insert and UNHEX('$hash') in where clause. That solve also the space earning