# Is Not BigInt Enough To House sha1?

Tags: mysql, sha1, bigint

I want to know if BigInt is enough in size.
I have created a registration.php where the user gets emailed an account activation link to click to verify his email so his account gets activated.

Account Activation Link is in this format:

[php]

```
$account_activation_link = 
"http://www.".$site_domain."/".$social_network_name."/activate_account.php?primary_website_email=".$primary_website_email."&account_activation_code=".$account_activation_code."";
```

[/php]

Account Activation Code is in this format:

$account_activation_code = sha1( (string) mt_rand(5, 30)); //Type Casted the INT to STRING on the 1st parameter of sha1 as it needs to be a STRING.

Now, the following link got emailed:
http://www.myssite.com/folder/activate_account.php?primary_website_email=my.email@gmail.com&account_activation_code=22d200f8670dbdb3e253a90eee5098477c95c23d

Note the account activation code that got generated by sha1:
22d200f8670dbdb3e253a90eee5098477c95c23d

But in my mysql db, in the "account_activation_code" column, I only see:
"22". The rest of the activation code is missing. Why is that ?
The column is set to BigInt. Is not that enough to house the Sha1 generated code ?
What is your suggestion ?

Thank You

Comment: IIRC, MySQL's `BigInt` — 64 bit long, but SHA1 is 160 bit long.

Comment: @PetSerAl SHA1 is also a string and not an int

Comment: @watzon It is depends on how you represent it. It is totally possible to represent hash value as a single number, given that you have a type to represent that big number. MySQL's `BigInt` is just not big enough.

Comment: @PetSerAl just making the BigInt bigger would not work though nor does it really solve his underlying issue. In order to make the SHA1 hash into an Integer you would have to convert the base. Just changing to a VARCHAR fixes the larger problem

Comment: @watzon SHA1 is binary. People are just used to seeing "hexencoded" dumps of it because it's easier to read.

Comment: @watzon *just making the BigInt bigger would not work though* I never say it would. *nor does it really solve his underlying issue* I never intent to address it either. I am only answering question in the title: *Is Not BigInt Enough To House sha1?*. Even if you convert hex string to number, `BigInt` is not big enough to store it.

Comment: See my answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247304/what-data-type-to-use-for-hashed-password-field-and-what-length/247627#247627

Answer (score 0):

Hashing methods like [SHA-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1) produce binary values that are on the order of 160+ bits long depending on the variant used. The common SHA256 one is 256 bits long. No cryptographic hash will fit in a 64-bit BIGINT field because 64-bit hashes are uselessly small, you'll have nothing but collisions.

Normally people store hashes as their hex-encoded equivalents in a `VARCHAR(255)` column. These can be indexed and perform well enough in most situations, especially one where you do periodic lookups based on clicks. From a performance and storage perspective there's no problems here.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: `BIGINT` is way too small.

A hash is basically a stream of bits (160 bits in the case of [SHA-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1)). While it's certainly possible to render those bits as a base 2 number and convert it to base 10, you need a really big storage to do so (as far as I know it's not common to see integer variables larger then 64 bits) and there aren't obvious advantages. [BIGINT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html) is a 64-bit type, thus cannot do the job.

Unless you have a good reason to store it as number, I'd simply go for either a [binary column type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/binary-varbinary.html) or its plain-text hexadecimal representation in a good old `VARCHAR` (the latter tends to be more practical to handle).

Comment: Please don't be the person on your team that stores hashes as raw binary in the database. This is unbelievably annoying as you can't cut-paste those values to do ad-hoc queries, and inspecting them takes a lot of extra work. The space savings is so marginal that unless you're dealing with literal trillions of these things you'll never notice.

Comment: @tadman You're right. I didn't want to recommend binary over text, I just wanted to emphasize the binary nature of hashes. I'll try to improve the wording.

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to store a string in a BigInt. That is your issue. SHA hashes are a mix of alphanumeric characters not just numbers. Change the field to a VARCHAR and you'll be fine

Comment: Watz,Ok, thanks. I will try. But, how many digits limit should I put for the VarChar here ? I can see 40 digits on this example but I'm not sure if it will always be 40 digits max or not.

Comment: @PhpLearner SHA1 hashes are 40 characters long

Comment: Cheers. Setting limit to 40 digits then.

Comment: @PhpLearner that should do it. Don't forget to accept the answer if it works for you

Comment: They're not mixes of "alphanumeric characters". You're just used to seeing hex-dumped versions which have 0-9 and a-f in them. Base-64 is something that uses a much broader spectrum of characters, but that encoding method isn't normally used for hashes.

Comment: I've been testing and problem not solved. Msql column either shows 2 digits or 3 but not 40.
The account activation link that gets emailed contains 40 digits, though as supposed to. For some reason, mysql is truncating the digits by 38 digits in the column "account_activation_code" VarChar(40).

Comment: @PhpLearner you changed it to a VARCHAR(40)? I can't think of any reason why it wouldn't be working unless you're converting the string to an int somewhere along the line

Comment: I don't know why the following code should convert to INT since the column is set to VARCHAR 40:

$account_activation_code = sha1( (string) mt_rand(5, 30)); //Type Casted the INT to STRING on the 1st parameter of sha1 as it needs to be a STRING.

Comment: @watz,

Changing column type to VARCHAR(40) still not work. Column trancates from 40 digs to 2 or 3.
And clicking the acc_activation_link that carries the acc_activation_code (40 digit code), shows:

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'mysqli_sql_exception' with message 'Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now' in /home/user/public_html/folder/activate_account.php:49 Stack trace: #0 /home/user/public_html/folder/activate_account.php(49): mysqli_prepare(Object(mysqli), 'UPDATE users SE...') #1 {main} thrown in /home/user/public_html/folder/activate_account.php on line 49

Comment: Alvaro Gonzales,
I get this same error when changing column type to BINARY like  you suggested. However, the column shows more than 2 or 3 digits. Shows this:

30000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

But this is no help because if sha1 generated that code then that code is not getting added by php into the account_activation_link. Therefore, changing column type to BINARY I do not think is the solution.

Comment: @PeterSa1,

I set the column "account_activation_code" to VARCHAR(160) like you hinted but no luck. 
The account_activation_link looks like this:

http://www.myssite.com/folder/activate_account.php?primary_website_email=my.email@gmail.com&account_activation_code=0ade7c2cf97f75d009975f4d720d1fa6c19f4897

The column holds the account activation code value like this: 0.
No relation between the account activation code in the column and in the account activation link.
Sha1 manages to generate account activation code on the account activation link but not add it in the mysql column.

Comment: Luckily, I went through somebody's reply again tonight on another forum (which I overlooked) and fixed it from:
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ssssssssssi', $username, ..);
to:
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'sssssssssss', $username, ..);
and my mysql column "account_activation_code" now holds 40 digits and no longer 2-3.
His advice was:
"You also need to make sure you don't have PHP trying to cast it to an integer prior to inserting it (such as by using i rather than s when binding). Otherwise PHP will take what digits it can and truncate the rest."
I'm sharing here where I went wrong.

Comment: I am being told that I have to switch column type to BINARY(20) and UNHEX. Else, it won't work for me always. Want to know opinions of programmers in StackOverFlow.