# Why SQL query with SHA2_256 returns NULL in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I need a hand on this, any comments will be highly appreciated.

I have a table *Users* with field *UserPassword*  with datatype *varchar(60)*

I insert on the table users from this select

```
SELECT HASHBYTES('SHA2_256','test') 
it insert its value (0x9F86D081884C7D659A2FEAA0C55AD015A3BF4F1B2B0B822CD15D6C15B0F00A08)
```

so far so good

the problems comes out when I want to retrieve user From table and it doesn't match the value of the field UserPassword.

```
Select u.UserName
from Users u
where UserPassword  = HASHBYTES('SHA2_256','test')
```

the query is executed with 0 results. why ???

the field UserPassword has the same datatype or am I wrong?
do I have to do any other cast to the value in order to match?

thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post the table DDL? I'm not able to reproduce this issue. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9faf2/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Up the datatype of user password to VARCHAR(1000) or something. The hash map returns 65 characters so it's getting truncated as 60.

Edit: This would fix it, but do what Dan said instead. That is more robust.

Comment: roger that, will do

Answer (score 1):

> I have a table Users with field UserPassword with datatype varchar(60)

[`HASHBYTES`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/hashbytes-transact-sql) returns varbinary(8000). Use that for your database data type to ensure the value is stored and compared properly.

Answer (score 1):

**field UserPassword has the same datatype?** or  **do any other cast to the value in order to match?**

It depends on the hashing algorithm you use. Hashing always produces a result of the same length, regardless of the input. It is typical to represent the binary hash result in text, as a series of hexadecimal digits. Or you can use the UNHEX() function to reduce a string of hex digits by half.

> SHA-256 generates a 256-bit hash value. You can use CHAR(64) or
>   BINARY(32)

NIST recommends using SHA-256 or higher for passwords. Lesser hashing algorithms have their uses, but they can be crackable.

You should secure your passwords before applying the hashing function. In this way password does not affect the length of the hash result.

**Edit:** Check this [Hashed password field and Length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247304/what-data-type-to-use-for-hashed-password-field-and-what-length) for more information