# Fix password hash getting truncated when imported to MySQL table

Tags: python, mysql, flask, bcrypt

I currently have a Flask app that registers a Username and password to a MySQL database. My problem is that using `Bcrypt` to hash passwords and then save to them to the database, the outputted hash gets truncated by MySQL. My function looks like this:

```
class PasswordResource(Resource):
    @app.route('/password', methods=['GET'])
    @jwt_required

    def sendPassword():
        data = get_jwt_identity()
        hashed_password = bcrypt.hashpw(data['user_password'].encode('utf8'), bcrypt.gensalt())
        print(hashed_password)
        return mysqldb.addPassword("{}".format(str(data['user_name'])),"{}".format(hashed_password))
```

and connects to the database:

```
def addPassword(Username,Userpassword):
    try:
        cursorObject = connection.cursor()
        cursorObject.execute("call sp_createPassword('{}'".format(Username)+",'{}')".format(Userpassword))
        connection.commit()
        connection.close()

    finally:
        return 'User added succesfully!'
```

However, the hash gets truncated by MySql even though I have tried various `VARCHAR()` for the password table. This is an error i get in console `Warning: (1265, u"Data truncated for column 'p_password' at row 1") self._do_get_result()`. My password column currently is configured to `VARCHAR(255), Not Null`. How can I fix this error and avoid having the hashes getting truncated?

**UPDATE**

This is would be the schema for my password table:

```
+---------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table         | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            |
+---------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| tbl_passwords | CREATE TABLE `tbl_passwords` (
  `user_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `user_number` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_number`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=12 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci |
+---------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Maybe this post is helpful to check the needed size  https://stackoverflow.com/a/247627/6655211

Comment: **WARNING**: **DO NOT** use a high-speed cryptographic hash like SHA256 for passwords, this makes common passwords trivial to crack. At the absolute least use a password-specific hashing function like [Bcrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt).

Comment: @tadman Taking your suggestion into account..will not be using SHA256 then.

Comment: It'd help if you showed a representative schema for the table with the problem. `SHOW CREATE TABLE` can give you that output. As always edit your question to include any new code, don't use comments where formatting impractical.

Comment: @tadman updated my question to show the schema.

Comment: Use `VARCHAR(255)` as a safe default for any "string" type fields. You're using a bizarre mix of `VARCHAR` and `CHAR`. Remember `CHAR` is fixed-length and not necessary under most circumstances.

Comment: @tadman So you would recommend using Bcrypt for user in my case?

Comment: Absolutely. It's literally a million times safer than SHA2-256.

Comment: @tadman tried a couple things with Bcrypt's hash, but it still gets truncated by MySQL..

Comment: Check how long the resulting string is from Bcrypt. It should be < 255 characters, and if not, something's wrong and it's not being encoded correctly or the schema isn't what you think it is.

Answer (score 1):

My issue was in my Procedure `sp_createpassword()` that added the password. In this procedure I had set for the `password` parameter to be `VARCHAR(20)` and obviously not enough for the hash. Silly error. Still, the suggestions of tadman were really helpful in setting up a proper DB.