# Is there any significant disadvantage in storing base64 in a SQL Server database over storing the same data as hexadecimal?

Tags: sql, sql-server, cryptography, relational-database

Most data that is of the nature of hash values* (see note below) are all stored in a relational database such as SQL Server in either [`BINARY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/binary-and-varbinary-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) data type or in [`CHAR`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/char-and-varchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) data type.

When stored in `CHAR`, [as a practice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/247627/303685) and not as the database implementation, they are *mostly* stored as hexadecimals. That is, they are stored by the *user of the database* or the *author of the code that uses the database* in *hexadecimals*, and not *by the database itself*.

So, my question is: why? Why store it only as hexadecimal? I'd like to store something of this nature in a `CHAR` field as base64.

It would take much less space, too.

**Stored as ASCII Plain Text**

For e.g. to store the text "Hello" in plain ASCII inside a `CHAR` type column, assuming that string was the only string I wanted to store and so I took a fixed length column, would take `CHAR(6)` (counting one `CHAR` for the null character).

**Stored in the Hexadecimal Notation**

Storing the same in hexadecimal would take a `CHAR(11)`, i.e. 10 hexadecimal characters plus 1 for the null character.

**Stored in the base64 notation**

Storing the same in base64 would take only a `CHAR(8)`, i.e. 5 characters + 1 null character taking up a total of 6 bytes in ASCII encoding, which equals 48 bits, which when translated into base64, would need only (48 / 6 = 8) 8 characters to express including the null character.

So, is there any reason why the hexadecimal notation is preferred? More importantly, is there any disadvantage I might be overlooking in storing data in the base64 notation?

---

***Data that is of similar nature:**

Data of the nature of has values, message digests, or checksums, or salts (for either hash functions or password based key derivation functions or for keys for encryption algorithms), etc.

Comment: Base 64 will typically increase the size of binary data by about 25%.  It is a format you might use when transporting information to and from your database, but you might not want to actually store your binary data in this format (rather, let your application worry about that).

Comment: Probably because binary data was harder to work with in eg SSMS so a character based form was adopted, and base16 was chosen because base64 wasn't around yet/implemented/popular and most coders get stuck in their ways. Feel free to use whatever is easiest for you to work with in your app

Comment: Who cares? Just store it as binary data - not any kind of text.

Comment: @MartinSmith I actually ended up doing that. :-)