# Hash::check is always false or null

Tags: laravel, hash, eloquent

Why when log in the Hash::check always is false or null?

This is part of my register controller. The password i save in a single table named 'password' which i hash with the method below

```
    ....
               $user = new Hause_users();
               $user->username = request('username');
               $user->Email = request('email');
               $user->password = Hash::make(request('password'));
               $user->First_Last_Name = request('first_last_name');


               $user->save();
```

Below is my log in controller with the Hash::check method where i check the current user, its hashed password in my DB named Hause_users, i get the string input password by the LogIn form and i try to match it with Hash::check. In this case the pass must be 123123.

Problem is it always return "Bye".

What i do wrong here?

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\userController;


use App\Model\Hause_users;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;

use Illuminate\Routing\Controller;


use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response;


class loginController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Handle an authentication attempt.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function authLogin(Request $request)
    {
       $data = Hause_users::where('username', '=', request('username'))->first();
        $password = ($data['password']);


             // dd($request->password);
        //dd($data['password']);

        $check = Hash::check($request->password, $data['password']);
           if($check){
               return 'welcome';
        }else{
            return 'Bye';
        }

        //echo($pass_in);

        }

}
```

Thanks for the suggestion i am using Hash::make method of laravel framework which is actually bcript behind the scenes. I just can understand why the Hash::check provided by Laravel does not match the user input with the hased password taken from my DB.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What data type to use for hashed password field and what length?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247304/what-data-type-to-use-for-hashed-password-field-and-what-length)

Comment: Thanks but not really. I am using Hash::make method of laravel framework which is actually bycript behind the scenes. I just can understand why the Hash::check does not match the user input with the hased password taken from the DB.

Comment: Yeah, I'm saying it's most likely because you aren't storing the hash properly in the database.

Comment: Not to mention you're checking against the string 'password' in your provided code...

Comment: @miken32 Thanks for your help, actually i am collecting it correctly the dd()'s are pulling out both the hashed string and user input. 
I have made a small CODE EDIT with some dd() checks that i am using.

Comment: I’m not saying you’re not storing the hash. I’m saying you’re probably not storing it completely. Did you look at the dupe? You don’t seem to be addressing the potential problems explained by the answers there. Where’s your migration?

Answer (score 0):

You should pass user input password to the 1st argument and pass the hashed password from DB to 2nd argument of `Hash::check` like this:

```php
/**
 * Handle an authentication attempt.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function authLogin(Request $request)
{
    $data = Hause_users::where('username', '=', request->username)->first();

    if (Hash::check($request->password, $data->password)) {
        return 'welcome';
    } else {
        return 'Bye';
    }
}
```

See [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/master/hashing) for more info.

Comment: No, it doesn't work like this. Besides your :: where clause is wrong.
Do i need to hash or get anything from the blade.template

Comment: @NikolaySabev What you mean it doesn't work? just try it.

Comment: i did  but still same old result condition jumps always to false

Answer (score 0):

check method is comparing between hashed password and entered password you should use it this way

```
$check = Hash::check($request->password,auth()->user()->password);
if($check)
{
// your condition
}
else{
// return what ever you want
}
```

Comment: No this is not useful, has no difference where i use the if condition

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue and it was in my blade template. I had some error check {{old 'password'}} that coused the incorrect string collision with the input. When i removed that part `value="{{ old('password') }}` all worked smooth.