# show PW in mySQL DB or create new user

Tags: mysql, database, passwords, usernametoken

I'm working on a project, continuing a work of somebody else I need to have user name and PW for the update I want to make I can access database it is a MYSQL database. I can see user names but I can't know the PW of any user to do my tests.

I tried to make a new user  using the insert tab in php my admin but the query generated was like this

```
INSERT INTO `user`
            (`id`, `username`, `auth_key`, `password_hash`, 
            `password_reset_token`, `email`, `status`, `created_at`, 
            `updated_at`, `central_branch`) 
VALUES ([value-1], [value-2], [value-3], [value-4], [value-5],
        [value-6],[value-7],[value-8],[value-9],[value-10])
```

where `auth_key`, `password_hash` generated from the pw in the view can any body help me either create user or know pw of any user

Comment: What language is the project coded in?

Comment: php  ....  yii2  the orginal form get username and pw then hash pw before inserting it

Answer (score 0):

In general, hashes are not reversible. So if the value of `password_hash` in your table is storing a hash, you can't get the original plaintext password back from that hash. You can replace it with a new hash string for a password you know, but you can't reverse the existing hash to get the password that was used to generate that hash.

If you can't ask the original developer, and that developer didn't leave any notes about the password for you, then you can only replace it with a new password hash.

If you can't do that because you don't have privilege to update the table, then you need to use the instructions for starting the MySQL Server without privilege enforcement, so you can make users and grant privileges for yourself to work on it. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/resetting-permissions.html

Comment: I have the previllage to update but  dontknow how to replace it with a new password hash can you help me? there is no way to contact the orginal developer

Comment: I cannot, because I don't know your application code. There are many ways to generate a hash, and I don't know which one is used in your code. You're going to have to read your code to find out.

Comment: We could make a guess at the hash function used based on the length of the hash strings (see my answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247304/what-data-type-to-use-for-hashed-password-field-and-what-length/247627#247627). But we still wouldn't know whether the hash is actually hashed multiple times from the input, and how many times.

Comment: <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([]); ?>

                <?= $form->field($model, 'username')->textInput(['autofocus' => true]) ?>

                <?= $form->field($model, 'email') ?>
    

                <?= $form->field($model, 'auth_key')->hiddenInput(['readonly' => true])?>
      <?= $form->field($model, 'password_hash')->hiddenInput(['readonly' => true])?>
    <?php $authItems=ArrayHelper::map($authItems,'name','name'); ?>
    

            <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

Comment: As far as I can tell, none of that describes the hashing function used to store your passwords. I'm not volunteering to tutor you on your whole app.