# Data type that mimics BINARY(64) in YugabyteDB

Tags: yugabytedb

[Question posted by a user on [YugabyteDB Community Slack](https://www.yugabyte.com/slack)]

I was wondering if anyone knows the proper data type that mimics `BINARY(64)` in SQL for storing hashed passwords in YugabyteDB?
I am looking to hash a password, store that and then generate a salt randomly on insert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CHAR(60) type. This is suggested alongside BINARY(64). Reference: [What data type to use for hashed password field and what length?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247304/what-data-type-to-use-for-hashed-password-field-and-what-length)

If your hash is not encoded as Base64 or hex or whatever, use `BYTEA`.