# How to define prefix index as primary key in liquibase?

Tags: spring, liquibase

I have a table in which the primary key value can be long.

When I try to redefine the primary column length, I get the following error

```
liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Specified key was too long; max key length is 3072 bytes
```

I'm guessing the above error is due to MySQL's default max index size, so it seems like my next best option atm is to define this primary key with a prefix index (or maybe expand the max index length here somehow).

Is there any way to do that with liquibase?

Comment: What data type are you trying to use for the primary key? I would choose a data type that fits in the max key length.

Comment: The column is currently defined as varchar(255). It represents an S3 file key. Do you have any suggestions on alternatives?

Comment: Varchar(255) works fine. Your column must be at least varchar(769) to return the error you show.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific. The current definition of varchar(255) is not enough, so I tried redefining it as varchar(1000), which is when I ran into the error. (I arbitrarily picked varchar(1000) because I wasn't sure what made sense for the S3 key in this case.) But upon looking into the max length for an S3 key, it looks to be 1024. So it seems something is wrong upstream, and my issue should be addressed there.

Comment: But it would be nice to know the answer to my question anyways :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to get Liquibase to define a primary key with an index prefix, but it won't help to use an index prefix anyway.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/object-keys.html says:

> The object key name is a sequence of Unicode characters with UTF-8 encoding of up to 1,024 bytes long.

Thus it's between 255 and 1024 *characters*, depending on how many of the characters are multibyte.

But MySQL index prefix syntax measures length in characters, not bytes.

So you would need to define an index prefix length of 1024 to handle S3 keys, but that's too long for a MySQL index definition.

You must define a different column as the primary key in this table. For example, you could use an MD5() hash of the S3 object key name, and [store that in a CHAR(32) or BINARY(16)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247304/what-data-type-to-use-for-hashed-password-field-and-what-length/247627#247627).

Comment: I was thinking I could define the index prefix to be whatever MySQL can handle, and just ignore the rest of the string. But the hash is a great suggestion, thank you very much!

Comment: If you define an index prefix on a unique key or primary key, then strings that are the same in that prefix will conflict. I'm not sure what the format of S3 object keys is (that is, whether the initial part is guaranteed to be unique or not), but the prefix index could prevent you from inserting legitimate distinct keys.

Comment: In my case, it is extremely unlikely that the prefix will conflict, but it's certainly still a possibility. So you're absolutely right, using a prefix index is probably not the best option for me.